# PHP convert output with linebreaks to a simple array and grouping

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

In an earlier question [PHP Bitwise compare values from database with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920578/php-bitwise-compare-values-from-database-with-an-array/#answer-65920916), one coder came up with a nice solution.

A "Bitwise AND" (&) operator seems to be an option:

```
<?php
$userrights = array(
    "UR_SWP"           => 1,
    "UR_BUHA"          => 2,
    "UR_AZ"            => 4,
    "UR_SA"            => 8,
    "UR_FIDI"          => 16,
    "UR_ADMIN"         => 32,
    "UR_LEAD"          => 64,
    "UR_AZ_EVENT"      => 128,
    "UR_SA_COMPLIANCE" => 256,
    "UR_CH"            => 512,
    "UR_USERMOD"       => 1024,
    "UR_SWP_GL"        => 2048,
    "UR_MEDB"          => 4096,
    "UR_SWP_GP"        => 8192,
    "UR_STAFF_DEPT"    => 16384,
    "UR_MEET_KEYUSER"  => 32768,
    "UR_MEET_ADMIN"    => 65536
);

$rows = array(1, 65, 2081, 2145, 18497, 32769);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($userrights as $key => $userright) {
        if ($userright & $row) {
            $result = $key.", ";
        }
    };
    echo "<br>";
}
foreach ($arr as $val) {
echo($val);
}

?>
```

---

This is the actual output before my explode:

```
UR_SWP,
UR_SWP, UR_LEAD,
UR_SWP, UR_ADMIN, UR_SWP_GL,
UR_SWP, UR_ADMIN, UR_LEAD, UR_SWP_GL,
UR_SWP, UR_LEAD, UR_SWP_GL, UR_STAFF_DEPT,
UR_SWP, UR_MEET_KEYUSER,
```

Now it's about bringing the output in the right format. This is what I would need, a simple array. But a "grouped" output. **UR_SWP, UR_SWP UR_LEAD, UR_SWP UR_ADMIN UR_LEAD UR_SWP_GL**

Now i get a strange array:

```
string(17) "UR_MEET_KEYUSER, " UR_MEET_KEYUSER,
```

but should be: (result of 2081 starts with the second UR_SWP).
`UR_SWP, UR_SWP UR_LEAD, UR_SWP UR_ADMIN UR_LEAD UR_SWP_GL`

As you can see, I just want to group the 3 values (the result of 2081) to one value in the newly created array then separate by delimiter and group the next values.

Comment: Well, no response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920578/php-bitwise-compare-values-from-database-with-an-array/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$userrights = array(
    "UR_SWP"           => 1,
    "UR_BUHA"          => 2,
    "UR_AZ"            => 4,
    "UR_SA"            => 8,
    "UR_FIDI"          => 16,
    "UR_ADMIN"         => 32,
    "UR_LEAD"          => 64,
    "UR_AZ_EVENT"      => 128,
    "UR_SA_COMPLIANCE" => 256,
    "UR_CH"            => 512,
    "UR_USERMOD"       => 1024,
    "UR_SWP_GL"        => 2048,
    "UR_MEDB"          => 4096,
    "UR_SWP_GP"        => 8192,
    "UR_STAFF_DEPT"    => 16384,
    "UR_MEET_KEYUSER"  => 32768,
    "UR_MEET_ADMIN"    => 65536
);

$rows = array(1, 65, 2081, 2145, 18497, 32769);
$groupedOutput = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $tempGroupedStr = "";
    foreach ($userrights as $key => $userright) {
    if ($userright & $row) {
        $tempGroupedStr .= $key." ";
    }
    };
    $groupedOutput[] = rtrim($tempGroupedStr);
    $tempGroupedStr = "";
}

print_r($groupedOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

$userrights = array(
    "UR_SWP"           => 1,
    "UR_BUHA"          => 2,
    "UR_AZ"            => 4,
    "UR_SA"            => 8,
    "UR_FIDI"          => 16,
    "UR_ADMIN"         => 32,
    "UR_LEAD"          => 64,
    "UR_AZ_EVENT"      => 128,
    "UR_SA_COMPLIANCE" => 256,
    "UR_CH"            => 512,
    "UR_USERMOD"       => 1024,
    "UR_SWP_GL"        => 2048,
    "UR_MEDB"          => 4096,
    "UR_SWP_GP"        => 8192,
    "UR_STAFF_DEPT"    => 16384,
    "UR_MEET_KEYUSER"  => 32768,
    "UR_MEET_ADMIN"    => 65536
);

$rows = array(1, 65, 2081, 2145, 18497, 32769);
$results = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $subGroup = [];
    foreach ($userrights as $key => $userright) {
        if ($userright & $row) {
            $subGroup[] = $key;
        }
    };

    // implode space, you can implode as. your need
    $results[] = implode(' ', $subGroup);    
    // if you want to keep the subgroup as an array
    // $results[] = $subGroup;
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually the output is: Array ( [0] => UR_SWP [1] => UR_SWP,UR_LEAD [2] => UR_SWP,UR_ADMIN,UR_SWP_GL [3] => UR_SWP,UR_ADMIN,UR_LEAD,UR_SWP_GL [4] => UR_SWP,UR_LEAD,UR_SWP_GL,UR_STAFF_DEPT [5] => UR_SWP,UR_MEET_KEYUSER ) Is there a way to output the group without a delimter like 
[4] => UR_SWP UR_LEAD UR_SWP_GL UR_STAFF_DEPT 
or replace limiter by another char like +
[4] => UR_SWP + UR_LEAD + UR_SWP_GL + UR_STAFF_DEPT

Comment: Changed the `,` with ` ` space in the implode method, you can implode with any delimiter you like. you can do plus with spaces `' + '`, what ever is your need